# CreateUserWizard control problem (password issue)?

Tags: asp.net, validation, createuserwizard

Every password that i enter and when i click the button, it tells me that the password is wrong. it activates this field in its properties: InvalidPasswordErrorMessage.

I suspect that the user tries to use the password to connect to the database.

Another weird thing, is even when a password fails to be created..(invalid), the control stores the record in the database... for example in the PasswordFailed in the members table, i get a date and the users details (The control did it in a few occassions, which is bad for login)..

The main issue however, is with the password always being invalid..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the membership configuration you will find attributes for setting minimum number of non alpanumeric characters, min length etc. Try lowering all such values and see if it accepts your passwords. A complex password like "abc%12U8" should also be accepted.

But the error message also displays upon db connection errors so you should test the connection to the database.

also the db identity should be a member of all the "aspnet_.*" roles on the database.

Comment: Actually, i have no membership attribute in the configuration class

Comment: Sorry if I got your question wrong but wasn't it about .net membership and the standard create user wizard? If so you should have a membership section in web.config containing the mentioned attributes.

Comment: It is about the control alone. I used to put some membership attributes before, but i deleted it.. The question isnt linked to membership. I dont see why the control wouldnt work without doing what you told me

Comment: I write what I do since I have seen the same error messages when membership was not properly configured. The control uses the membership to create users and rejection of user creation can cause the message to be displayed.